# Rails getting data through multiple models?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, associations

I'm working with rails and I have this predicament:

My associations setup is like this:

Team -> Player -> Match -> Game -> PlayerStats

as in, teams have players, players have matches, matches are best of five and have games, and each player in the game has stats.

However, if I want to get a players total goals I'd have to do loop through all their matches and for every match look at every game and pull their stats from each game.

Will this be too taxing if I do this for multiple stats when I load a page? Is there perhaps a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: Now is a great time to look into and learn about database views, aggregations, and windows. Here's a good start: http://brewhouse.io/2016/08/04/sql-in-rails.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema should look like this

```
Team(id, name)
Player(id, name)
Match(id, name)
Game(id, name, match_id)
PlayerStat(id, match_id, team_id, player_id, game_id, goal_count)
```

For players total goals query will be

```
player.player_stats.sum(:goal_count)
```

which is same as

```
PlayerStat.where(player_id: 2).sum(:goal_count)
```

Comment: Ah! That makes much more sense. Thank you! While I have you here, all of the data in the database is going to be entered by me (none created by users on the site). Is my best bet just to seed the database using seed.rb or is there a better way for me to directly change the data?

Comment: Note, if you want to get stats for a whole team, you can combine ActiveRecord queries like this: `players = Player.top.first(5); stats = PlayerStat.where(player_id: players)`. This will let you avoid poorly performing N+1 queries.

Comment: @Fianite Yes. seeds.rb will be fine.

Comment: @Fianite, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I'll do that right away, but maybe you can help me out with one last thing. I want to be able to do team.matches, so I need to give Match a team_id. However, there are two teams in a match, how can I give it two team_ids?

Comment: @Fianite well this depends on your use case, you can have two team id columns in match table like home_team_id and away_team_id or you can have has_many through association (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), where you will create another table say Participation(match_id, team_id). So a match can have two teams.